# vsftp hangs at "150 Here comes the directory listing."

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

In a vsftpd server enviroment, shared various directories from nfs mountpoints, I can log in without problem, but when I send the first "ls", the vsftp give me the directory listing:

```
lftp user1@10.10.10.10:~> ls
-rw-rw-rw-    1 1160     1016          392 Jun 06 09:28 test.gif
```

but not give me the shell again (lftp client). In the server log I can see that the last message is:

```
"150 Here comes the directory listing."
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall settings, chances are you are not allowing the PASV ports through, or maybe port 20 ftp-data. Try opening TCP ports 50000-55000 on your firewall and add the below to your vsftpd.conf.

```
pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_max_port=55000
```

If using active mode then you should just need port 20, if using passive then you should be setting those ports on your firewall and the matching in the ftp config.

Here is a quick overview on Active vs Passive
http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem on my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu machine. I had ports 50000-51000 set for the passive mode in vsftpd.conf, and I had to open the ports on the security group AWS firewall settings.